# Weil pairings on abelian varieties restricted to subgroups of a given order

Tags: abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety of dimension $g$ defined over a number field $K$. Suppose $A$ has a principal polarization and $\ell$ is a prime number. We have a Weil pairing:

$$
e_\ell: A[\ell]\times A[\ell] \rightarrow \mu_\ell
$$

I dont know if the Weil pairing is unique, so my question is as follow:
Given a subgroup $G\subset A[\ell]$ of order $\ell^2$, is there a Weil pairing $e_\ell$ (eventually depending on $G$) such that there exist $P,Q\in G$ and $e_\ell(P,Q)$ is a primitive $\ell$-th root of unity?

I know from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208386/n-th-root-of-unity-in-n-th-division-field-of-abelian-variety/208405) that for any point $P\in G$, there exists a point $Q\in A[\ell]$ such that $e_\ell(P,Q)$ is a primitive $\ell$-th root of unity. Thanks in advance for comments and answers.

Comment: I am not sure what you call a "Weil pairing on $G$", but if you mean the restriction of the Weil pairing (which is unique and canonical), the answer is obviously no: just take for $G$ a totally isotropic subspaces of $A[\ell]$.